# Renormalization on noncommutative torus

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01479.pdf) of renormalization of field theory on noncommutative torus. At the end of chapter 6 there is the following statement
"Although our analysis is far from being exhaustive, we believe it strongly
suggest that the $\varphi^4$ theory on $\mathbb{T}_\theta^4$ is renormalizable." This paper was published in April. Are there some new results in this branch or is it still an open problem ?